# How to get month and its days in moment?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm going to create a calendar using moment.js, now I want to know how to get months and days for each month? I found this code but I didn't understand what it does:

```
function generateMonth() {
    var weeks = [];
    var done = false, date = moment().clone(), monthIndex = moment().month(), count = 0;
    while (!done) {
        weeks.push({ days: generateDays(moment().clone(), moment()) });
        date.add(1, "w");
        done = count++ > 2 && monthIndex !== date.month();
        monthIndex = date.month();
    }
}
function generateDays(date, month) {
    var days = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        days.push({
            number: date.date(),
            isCurrentMonth: date.month() === month.month(),
            isToday: date.isSame(new Date(), "day")
        });
        date = date.clone();
        date.add(1, "d");
    }
    return days;
}
```

Comment: Step number one. Learn what that code does.

Comment: go for http://fullcalendar.io/ , arshaw has done everything  you want